# Add files to Listbox via Thread?

Tags: c#, winforms

in my application i want to add files into my list box.
if my file isn't pcap extension i want to send the file path to my class and convet it to pcap extension and then add this file to my Listbox.
in case i am choose to add namy files the GUI not responding until my application finish to add or convert this file and i wonder how to add the option to do all this via threads.

```
private void btnAddfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.Stream stream;
    OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    thisDialog.InitialDirectory = (lastPath.Length > 0 ? lastPath : "c:\\");
    thisDialog.Filter = "(*.snoop, *.pcap, *.cap, *.net, *.pcapng, *.5vw, *.bfr, *.erf, *.tr1)" +
        "|*.snoop; *.pcap; *.cap; *.net; *.pcapng; *.5vw; *.bfr; *.erf; *.tr1|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
    thisDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    thisDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;
    thisDialog.Multiselect = true;
    thisDialog.Title = "Please Select Source File";

    if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (thisDialog.FileNames.Length > 0)
        {
            lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(thisDialog.FileNames[0]);
        }

        foreach (String file in thisDialog.FileNames)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((stream = thisDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (stream)
                    {
                        string fileToAdd = string.Empty;
                        Editcap editcap = new Editcap();


                            BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                            backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                            backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
                            (s3, e3) =>
                            {
                                if (!editcap.isLibpcapFormat(file))
                                {
                                    fileToAdd = editcap.getNewFileName(file);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file);
                                }
                            });

                            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
                                (s3, e3) =>
                                {
                                    listBoxFiles.Items.Add(fileToAdd);
                                });

                            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

                        lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(thisDialog.FileNames[0]);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you seen the `BackgroundWorker` class?

Comment: i know BackgroundWorker class and use it in my application but here i dont know how to use it and prevent try to add files before they return from the convert

Comment: You probably need [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) if you want to access WinForms elements in another thread.

Comment: @AlvinWong You shouldn't need `Invoke` at all to solve this problem.  You should, if at all possible (here it is) use abstractions such as `BackgroundWorker`, `Task`, or `await` to marshal between threads for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is freezing because you're doing a lot of work in the UI thread.  You need to move the long running tasks to a background thread and then just update the UI in the UI thread.

The first thing that you need to do, in order to do that, is seperate out your long running task from your UI manipulation.  Currently you're intermingliing the two, which is what's causing your confusion as to how to map it to a `BackgroundWorker`.

As long as you don't need to be updating the listbox iteratively and it's okay to just add all of the items at the end all at once (that's what I would expect out of a listbox) you can simply do your file IO in one place, adding the results into a collection of some sort (`List` is likely appropriate here) and then, separately, you can add all of the items in the list to your `ListBox` (or use data binding).

Once you make that change the move to using something like a `BackgroundWorker` is quite easy.  The IO work that populates the `List` goes in the `DoWork`, runs in the background, and then sets the `Result`.   The `RunWorkerCompleted` event then takes that lists and adds the items to the `ListBox`.

If you have a compelling need to add the items to the listbox as you go, so you see one item, then the next, etc. over time, then just think of it as "reporting progress" and use the relevant progress reporting functionality built into `BackgroundWorker`.  Update the progress inside of the loop, and in the progress reported event handler take the value given to you and put it in the `ListBox`.

Here is an implementation:

```
private void btnAddfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.Stream stream;
    OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    thisDialog.InitialDirectory = (lastPath.Length > 0 ? lastPath : "c:\\");
    thisDialog.Filter = "(*.snoop, *.pcap, *.cap, *.net, *.pcapng, *.5vw, *.bfr, *.erf, *.tr1)" +
        "|*.snoop; *.pcap; *.cap; *.net; *.pcapng; *.5vw; *.bfr; *.erf; *.tr1|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
    thisDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    thisDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;
    thisDialog.Multiselect = true;
    thisDialog.Title = "Please Select Source File";

    if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (thisDialog.FileNames.Length > 0)
        {
            lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(thisDialog.FileNames[0]);
        }

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            //TODO consider moving everything inside of the `DoWork` handler to another method
            //it's a bit long for an anonymous method
            foreach (String file in thisDialog.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((stream = thisDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        using (stream)
                        {
                            Editcap editcap = new Editcap();
                            if (!editcap.isLibpcapFormat(file))
                            {
                                string fileToAdd = editcap.getNewFileName(file);
                                backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, fileToAdd);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, file);
                            }


                            lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(thisDialog.FileNames[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        };

        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged +=
            (s3, arguments) =>
            {
                listBoxFiles.Items.Add(arguments.UserState);
            };

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
}
```

Comment: see my update, now i am using backgroundWorker but the GUi still freeze

Comment: @user1710944 Your `BackgroundWorker` is a *much* to local of a scope.  95% of your code should be inside of the `DoWork` event handler.  The button click handler should do nothing at all besides showing the dialog, creating the BGW, assigning event handlers, and starting it.  It should do no actual work at all.

Comment: can i have an code example of what you try to say ? (i am a new developer..)

Comment: @user1710944 You're most of the way there already.  As I said in my post, you need to seperate the collection of the data from updating of the UI.  You should be creating a collection, such as a `List`, and putting the data in the list inside of your loop.  You should then be adding the items from that list to the `ListBox` after the end of your loop.  Once you do that, the entire `foreach` loop can go in the `DoWork` handler, and the entire loop for updating the `ListBox` can go in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.  The fact that you're new is *why* you to need to do it yourself.

Comment: is it batter to add the item to my ListBox every time the file ready ? for example if i need to add many big files i want to see the files adding to my ListBox "ongoing" instead of waiting the loop to finish (can take 1 minute) - maybe something like Queue ?

Comment: @user1710944 That would then make the last paragraph in my answer apply.  You want to use "progress reporting" aspects of the BGW.  You still do the `DoWork` loop the same way, it contains the entire `foreach`, but instead of adding an item to a list, you call `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, someData)` and then use the data in the `ProgressReported` event to update the listbox.

Comment: this is i think beyond my skills for now, that's why i ask an example, btw see my update

Comment: Trigger a ProgressChange (backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(...). Then you can add the item with the ProgressChanged event.

Comment: i don't know much about event, can i have short example ?

Comment: @user1710944 You seem to think the problem is much harder than it really is.  Anywhere you are currently trying to add an item to your `Listbox` you should instead be calling `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, dataToAdd)`, and the progress reported event handler just takes the data parameter and adds it to the listbox.  You will have fundimental problems with your current approach of having `N` backgroundworkers, you should only have 1 BackgroundWorker for a task like this.

Comment: @user1710944 You're already handling events in your current code, you just do exactly what you're doing there, but for an event with a different name.

Comment: i did not understand what to do with dataToAdd

Comment: i added backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, dataToAdd); after listBoxFiles.Items.Add(fileToAdd);

Comment: @user1710944 It should be *in place of* adding the item to the listbox, in the `DoWork` handler, not *after*.  The listbox modification should be in the `ProgressReported` event.

Comment: i add it inside the else statement, but still what to do with dataToAdd ?

Comment: @user1710944 You put in the data that you want to add to the listbox.

Comment: still having problems with it, can i have example ?

Comment: @user1710944 Given that you've made a good faith attempt to implement the post as I suggested it, I have not added a coded solution.  Note that I went out of my way to avoid changing more than I needed to; there are a number of aspects of your code I would change that are unrelated to this particular problem.

Comment: @user1710944 You commented 30 seconds too late. =p

Comment: thank you very very much, i will jump inside your fixes and try to learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with BackgroundWorker:
Add a backgroundWorker to your form via the Toolbox.

Start it with:

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new string[] {parm1, parm2});
```

Add a events to backgroundWorker (Properties window)

Use DoWork to do your calculations. Then use RunWorkerCompleted to apply the settings.

Comment: see my update, now i am using backgroundWorker but the GUi still freeze

Comment: Did you step through your code to see where it freeze? Why don't you put: 'editcap editcap = new Editcap();if (!editcap.isLibpcapFormat(file))' inside the backgroundWorker?

Comment: i update my code again and now its not freezing but i think the best way to do it is to implement something like Queue